# List Comprehensions and Loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, nested

I'm currently going through different Python3 challenges on Hackerrank and I ran into this problem that caught me off guard. I found the solution but I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around how it works. I'm familiar with loops in python but I can't seem to trace the code step by step.

### Problem

You are given three integers *X, Y, and Z* representing the dimensions of a cuboid along with an integer *N*. You have to print a list of all possible coordinates given by on a 3D grid where the sum of is not equal to *N*.

### Input Format

Four integers X, Y, Z, and N each on four separate lines, respectively.

### Constraints

Print the list in lexicographic increasing order.

### Sample Input

```
1
1
1
2
```

### Sample Output

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

### Solution

```
x, y, z, n = (int(input()) for _ in range(4))
print([[a, b, c] for a in range(x+1) for b in range(y+1) for c in range(z+1) if a + b + c != n])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's think about how list comprehensions work.

The list comprehension you've posted works like the following loops:

```
l = []
for a in range(x):
    for b in range(y):
        for c in range(z):
            if a+b+c!= n:
                l.append([a,b,c])
print(l)
```

So, we loop across all possible values of *a*,*b*,and *c*, and find the triplets that satisfy our condition.

Comment: No problem! Anytime